# PHP __toString() Not working properly?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to learn PHP Objected Oriented Programming but during the video tutorial, I am getting an error while the tutorial presenter does not have the same issue!

**PHP Code**:

```
<?php


class Player {

public $score = 10;
public $name = "";

public function __construct($score,$name) {

    $this->score = $score;
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function __destruct() {

    echo "Object With Name ".$this->name." has been destroyed";
}

public function __toString() {
    echo "The Object with name ".$this->name." has been echoed</br>";
}

}


$newPlayer = new Player(50,"Ahmad");


echo $newPlayer;


?>
```

I am getting following error:

```
The Object with name Ahmad has been echoed
Catchable fatal error: Method Player::__toString() must return a string value in D:\xampp\htdocs\php_oop\index.php on line 30
```

When I change `echo` to `return` I get the following output which should not be happening as I am not unsetting the object. Why would the `__destruct()` function be called when `echo` is changed to `return` in the `toString()`?

The error becomes:

```
The Object with name Ahmad has been echoed
Object With Name Ahmad has been destroyed
```

Comment: You should use `return` instead of `echo` in your `__toString()` method.

Comment: @Raptor : yes exactly when I use `return` so then the `__destruct()` get's called too upon echo??? Please properly read the question..!

Comment: It's a **normal** behavior that Destructor is called, as the object will be garbage-collected when the script finished execution.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it by replacing `echo` with `return` in the `__destruct()` method too..! :D

Comment: wait. Destructor doesn't require returning anything. By replacing `echo` with `return`, you just hide the output of the text & the Destructor is still executed.

Comment: @Raptor : So why `echo` shouldn't be used instead of `return` in methods???

Comment: @Raptor : So do you mean when I echo Object so destruct method can't be avoided to be called???

Comment: If you don't add Destructor, nothing will be executed. In fact, it's quite rare to add a destructor in PHP class, as PHP itself will clean up stuff after finished running the script.

Comment: So you mean that `__destruct()` method is also executed even If I don't `unset` the object manually on it's own and on every call to the object or just at the end of script finishing execution?

Comment: Php kills everything at the end of the script execution, so every destructor method in every object created during the scrips execution will be called. Yours happens to echo something, hence why you see the output

Comment: Because php works this way, the use of destructors in userland code is pretty rare - they are only usefull if you need to free resources early, for example in a tight loop or in a long running task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add return statement.

```
return "The Object with name ".$this->name." has been echoed</br>";
```

Your script ends at the end of this file, That's why destructor is called!

Comment: This answer still stands true after reading your question properly :)

Comment: I did read it properly, and I just read it again.... don't see anything wrong with the answer... try to add sleep statement after echoing your object... you will see that it will get destroyed after the sleep statement

Comment: I knew about return so I used return too so this isn't anything new for me then...! :D :P

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is like one above:

```
return "The Object with name ".$this->name." has been echoed</br>";
```

Destruct method is called when you are done with your object. In your case after:

```
echo $newPlayer;
```